# Installing curl on Ubuntu 18.04 uninstall libcurl3

Tags: 18.04, curl

Trying to install curl on my Ubuntu 18.04 requires me to remove some stuff that other software in my system needs to run.

To be able to install curl from `apt install curl` I had to do this:

```
aptitude install curl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  curl libcurl4{ab}
0 packages upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 373 kB of archives. After unpacking 1,036 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcurl3 : Conflicts: libcurl4 but 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.7 is to be installed
 libcurl4 : Conflicts: libcurl3 but 7.58.0-2ubuntu2 is installed
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Remove the following packages:
1)     libcurl-openssl1.0-dev [7.58.0-2ubuntu2 (bionic, now)]
2)     libcurl3 [7.58.0-2ubuntu2 (bionic, now)]



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  curl libcurl4{a}
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libcurl-openssl1.0-dev{a} libcurl3{a} libssl1.0-dev{u}
0 packages upgraded, 2 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 373 kB of archives. After unpacking 8,252 kB will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] Y
```

To restore my php application I have to do:

`apt install libcurl3 libcurl-openssl1.0-dev`

How can I find a way to have both in my system?

Answer (score 1):

curl binary is linked only with newest libcurl4.
You need to:

```
apt install libcurl4 libcurl4-openssl-dev curl
```

to have all the newest. I suggest to compile curl manually if you want to be linked with "libcurl3 libcurl-openssl1.0-dev"

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. My question is how I can have both curl from the apt manager, and keep `libcurl3 libcurl-openssl1.0-dev`